# What qualifies for primal ancient items?

Tags: diablo-iii

Do the items drop only in level 70 rifts? Or do they drop everywhere after finishing a level 70 rift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [patch notes for Update 2.5](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/20529333/patch-250-ptr-notes-3-10-2017):

> Note: Primal Ancients will only begin dropping after a character on the player’s account has reached Greater Rift 70 Solo

So you must complete a solo 70 greater rift to unlock the *chance* for them to drop, but they can drop from any source (regular loot drops/bounty caches/upgrade through the cube, even Kadala!)  This must be done for each game type (once for Hardcore, Softcore, and Season/Nonseason of each of those).

I can personally attest to getting a primal from Kadala (gambling with blood shards).  Now my Templar has a real nice [Freeze of Deflection](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/freeze-of-deflection).

And here is [video evidence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6gyd8MaulE) of the cube creating one as well.

Comment: Yes. This weekend Kadala gave my monk a primal ancient crusader shield.

Comment: @ceving Oh what? Does Kadala drop off-class-specifics now?

Comment: @OrcJMR No my fault. I got it from a bounty chest.